# Access undefined properties on number type

Tags: javascript

I noticed that I can access arbitrary properties on number types without generating an error (at least in chrome):

```
123[1]    //undefined
```

I have to determine if the current item of an array is another array or a number, and this would come in handy. Is this behaviour reliable across all JS engines or is there a chance that this will generate an error somewhere?

Comment: You can access nonexistent properties of any object in Javascript.

Comment: Should work, it's basically the same as `123['0']`, or `(123).someNonExistentProperty`. If the value is `null` or `undefined`, it won't work.

Comment: Wait until you have to edit that code in a while, you'll get the "wtf was I thinking here" feeling. Make your code readable and don't rely on side effects or hacks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have to determine if the current item of an array is another array or a number...

And you couldn't use `!isNaN(value) || Array.isArray(value)`?

> and this would come in handy.

I really don't think it would.

> Is this behaviour reliable across all JS engines...

Yes, and [it's defined in the Property Accessors part of the ECMAScript spec](http://es5.github.io/#x11.2.1).

> or is there a chance that this will generate an error somewhere?

So long as the value isn't `null` or `undefined` you can use `[]` syntax to access properties of the object. It's common to call functions from numbers, but with decimal points it looks weird:

```
100..toString() //'100'
```

Answer (score 1):

To check the type of an item in Javascript, don't risk and use `typeof`, best way to determine an object type

http://javascript.info/tutorial/type-detection